# htaccess internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

When I goto http://example.com/not-here I get an internal server error instead of an 404, here is my htaccess file (it removes the extension so abc.php can be accessed as example.com/abc instead of example.com/abc.php):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

DirectoryIndex login.php index.php

ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?type=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?type=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?type=500
```

Its proberly something really simple but I cannot see it, any help is appriciated

Comment: @akond: I cannot access the logs its on a shared server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have in the .htaccess the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrited
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php?rewrited=1 [L,QSA]

DirectoryIndex login.php index.php

ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?type=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?type=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?type=500
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I run into this is comment out lines. Comment out the rewrite section and see if that works. To comment out code just put a # as the first character. It's all about narrowing the code down to the culprit line.

Comment: its the "RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]" which is causing it, any suggestions?

Comment: Let me try and look tonight. I'm on a wamp machine here don't have htaccess until this evening. Did anubhava answer above help you?

Comment: I ended up using akond's answer

Answer (score 0):

`internal server error` is being caused by infinite looping of your RewriteRule.

Just change your RewriteRule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)(?<!\.php)$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

`Negative lookbehind (?<!\.php)` will prevent more than one **internal redirections**.